# Recurrence relations and conditional expectations

Tags: probability

An urn contains $m$ black balls and $n$ white balls. Balls are drawn one at a time without replacement. Let $X_{m,n}$ be the number of draws required so that all black balls are drawn from the urn.

Derive a recurrence relation between $\mathbb{E}[X_{m,n}]$, $\mathbb{E}[X_{m-1,n}]$, and $\mathbb{E}[X_{m,n-1}]$.

I started by conditioning on the first draw to obtain a recurrence relation in terms of $X_{m,n}$, $X_{m-1,n} $ and $X_{m,n-1}$ as
$$X_{m,n} = \frac{m}{m+n} X_{m-1,n} + \frac{n}{m+n}X_{m,n-1},$$
but I cannot proceed further.

Comment: Your recursion is almost correct, except that you should replace $X_{m,n}$ by $\mathbb{E}(X_{m,n})$ and add a $+1$. Note also that your recursion as it stands would yield non-integer values for $X_{m,n}$.

Comment: Thanks Eckhard! I'm further supposed to prove that $\mathbb{E}[X_{3,2}] = \frac92$.

I should take expectations throughout and add $1$ on the right-hand side twice?

Comment: You should add one once. You can compute $\mathbb{E}[X_{3,2}]$ using the recursion together with suitable initial values that you determine directly.

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot!